# Difference between two rules: iptables

Tags: iptables

What is the difference between these two rules?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP    
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

If I want to block access to websites that uses HTTP, should I use the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really refer to the [man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) in the first instance and then ask a question here if you still have something you are not sure about. The `INPUT` chain is used to process packets arriving at the host. The `OUTPUT` chain is used to process packets sent from the host.

Specifically:

> It contains the built-in chains INPUT (for packets destined to local sockets), FORWARD (for packets being routed through the box), and OUTPUT (for locally-generated packets).

If you wanted to block your Linux machine from accessing HTTP websites, you would use the second option.